# Is there a neat way in syntax glossing to indicate "these are all optional, but at least one of them must be there"?

Tags: syntax, interlinear-gloss

I'm talking about a general case of the following situation:

```
*( (x) (y) (z) (w) ) lorem ipsum
```

where the positions for the optional elements are not contiguous.

For example, they may occupy the following positions:

```
(x) lorem (y) (z) ipsum (w)
```

**but**

```
* lorem ipsum
```

Is there a succinct way to indicate this is the case?

Comment: Not if you intend to display it on one line. Presence vs absence is one thing; position changing is a different matter and doesn't play happily with regular expressions and their ilk.